# How do you add a search bar to angular material?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

I am trying to add a search input to an `<md-toolbar>` but there doesn't seem to be any styling for this. It seems adding a search bar would be a common header element so perhaps I am missing something.

```
<md-toolbar md-theme="input">
    <md-input-container flex>
    <md-icon class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</md-icon>
    <input ng-model="search.notes" placeholder="Search here">
    </md-input-container>
</md-toolbar>
```

Then in the JS:

```js
app.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('input')
        .primaryPalette('blue')
        .accentPalette('pink')
        .warnPalette('red')
        .backgroundPalette('grey');
}]);
```

However, while the element does show up - it's clear this is not the intended way it should be used since neither the spacing, font-color, or alignment match up.

http://codepen.io/Xeoncross/pen/rLxEqv

Comment: So what's missing? Expectations are not clear

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't solve the problem of trying to use `md-input` inside a toolbar/header. You can make `md-content` look like a toolbar of sorts by making the content area dark so it stands out from regular `md-content` blocks. Kind of a work around the problem if you don't mind black.

```
<md-content md-theme="input" layout="column" layout-padding>
  <md-input-container style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0">
     <md-icon class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</md-icon>
     <input ng-model="search.notes" placeholder="Search here">
  </md-input-container>
</md-content>
```

and the theme js:

```
app.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('input')
      .primaryPalette('blue')
      .dark();                 // <----- Note
  }
]);
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/Xeoncross/pen/jrWgqY